# add subview to custom uiview in interfacebuilder

Tags: iphone, ios

I have made a `custom UIView` composed of several subviews and added it to a Nib file. 
The view is loading correctly, but my problem arises when I try to add a `UIView` to my `custom UIView` from InterfaceBuilder. 
I would like the added subviews to go to the topmost subview of my custom `UIView`, but not surprisingly, the subviews are added to the root `custom UIView`.

I could do some magic in the `init` of the `custom UIView`, moving the added view around.

is there any alternatives?

Any thought on best practice to solve this?

Comment: Shouldn't you be able to move the view around in Object section in the left panel of the Interface builder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be any clever solution.
Instead i ended up overriding `layoutSubviews` like this:

```
-(void)layoutSubviews
{    
    [super layoutSubviews];
    for (UIView *subview in self.subviews){
        if (![self.internalViews containsObject:subview]) {
            [subview removeFromSuperview];
            CGRect f =subview.frame;
            f.origin.y += self.frame.origin.y;
            subview.frame = f;
            [self.contentContainer addSubview:subview];

        }
    }
}
```

Doing construction of the view i added all by subviews to the array `internalViews`. The `contentContainer` is the view intended to serve as parent for all InterfaceBuilder added view.

Answer (score 0):

That seems to be right, since when you add the customView, int the nib file, you dont have access to its child subView, that means adding views to this custom view, will add them to the root view and not the childs,

As you said you will have to do some workaround to make this work, such as using tags to define the views and then move them by code

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your `Custom UIView` to `subview of your Root view` and all other subviews of root UIView as a `subview of your Custom View`.So that you can get what exactly you want.
You IB hierarchy should be like below...

```
 --->Root UIView
      --->Custom UIView
           --->UItextField
           --->UIlabel
           --->UiimageView
```

If you adding your `Custom UIView in a code`, then you need to connect `IBoutlet` for all subviews and then make them all as a `subview of your custom view`.